# file picker should accept pdf, docx,doc but accepting only pdf

Tags: input, input-type-file

I have file picker and what I need is my file picker should accept only `pdf, docx and doc`. 
What I did as follows:

```
<input name="Upload Saved Replay" type="file" accept="application/pdf,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"/>
```

**But it only accepting pdf. Not taking doc and docx**

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/santhucool007/wbn1xw6a/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<input name="Upload Saved Reply" type="file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx"/>
```

This accepts any files with names ending with the suffixes '.pdf', '.doc' and '.docx'